# Is this password function with sha256 and PBKDF2HMAC + salt secure to encrypt your local passwords in python?

Tags: python, security, encryption, passwords

Iam currently working on a way to safely store my private keys in a chat application I make.
I want to find a way to encrypt the keys with a password so if someone gets access to my computer they don't have my keys to use and during login i can simply type in my password to decrypt the keys and use them.
I found this password function using sha256 + PBKDF2HMAC with 100000 iterations and a salt  but I wonder how safe it is and if someone could crack it with bruteforce asuming Iam using a password with at least 8 charaters with both letters and numerals.

This is just a demonstration:

```
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import secrets

password_file = b'My list with passwords.'
login_salt = secrets.token_hex(16).encode()
```

## during login

```
def login(crypt_info):
    password = input("Enter password to login:").encode()
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256,
        length=32,
        salt=login_salt,
        iterations=100000,
        backend=default_backend(),
    )
    decryption_key = (base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password)))
    decryption_key_fernet = Fernet(decryption_key)
    decrypt_info = decryption_key_fernet.decrypt(crypt_info).decode()
    print(decrypt_info)
```

## encrypting keys

```
def encrypt():
    password = input("Enter password to register:").encode()
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256,
        length=32,
        salt=login_salt,
        iterations=100000,
        backend=default_backend(),
    )
    encryption_key = (base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password)))
    encryption_key_fernet = Fernet(encryption_key)
    encrypt_info = encryption_key_fernet.encrypt(password_file)
    print(encrypt_info)
    login(encrypt_info)


encrypt()
```

Comment: Now, It is about your password's strength. A good password like the ones generated with a dicewire can be beyond anybody's search. See [XKCD 936](https://xkcd.com/936/)